# Azure Data Factory - Collection reference failing when only 1 record

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to copy an XML into a database using a "Copy Activity".

XML file has a nested structure so I have defined a "Collection reference" at "Room" level:

[image: Collection reference screenshot]

If there are several records in the array Copy Activity works OK:

```
(...)
<Rooms>
  <Room>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Code>001</Code>
    <Beds>1</Beds>        
  </Room>  
  <Room>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Code>002</Code>
    <Beds>2</Beds>        
  </Room>  
</Rooms>
(...)
```

But when there is only 1 record in the array Copy Activity doesn't copy anything:

```
(...)
<Rooms>
  <Room>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Code>001</Code>
    <Beds>1</Beds>        
  </Room>  
</Rooms>
(...)
```

Is there a fix/workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

In Copy Activity, **For records where the array marked as collection reference is empty and the check box is selected, the entire record is skipped.**

[image]

Please Refer this documentation- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping

Comment: Thanks, but is this case the array is not empty. It has one, and only one, item. This should work. Shouldn't it?